# Garage door - bracket coming off

Tags: garage, garage-door

I have a garage door bracket coming off the door and I have no clue how to fix it.

The bracket is held in place all these years with 4 screws and probably some sort of industrial glue.. now, the entire bracket is coming off and hence the garage door jus opens up. I tried jus pulling the door down and putting the bracket back in place to give a facade that all is well with the door and had few handy men come and take a look and provide advice on how to fix.

Here are some pictures that explain what is going on - https://photos.app.goo.gl/WfVsyRJVarF7yKYNA

As you can see from the pictures, the underlying metal sheet / (probably wooden) garage door are now under going some wear and are no longer holding those 4 screws in place and the screws are coming off ... see picture - https://photos.app.goo.gl/bPug4HujUc9xQtmK6

Any suggestions on which parts I can bring from Home Depot / Lowes to fix ?

I tried reaching out to handy-men but none of them have a clue on how to fix and are not returning after looking at the problem :)

Is my only option to replace the door or is there any suggestions / advice on how to fix this to be in place? Would anyone experienced here suggest adding some sort of a fastener screw through the fastener hole ? -- https://photos.app.goo.gl/toaN8jduBmvpXNEZ7

NOTE: I am not an expert repair man and can do basic repairs around the house and can do most basic things. if this is something that requires expert skills to fix, I may jus as well fix through a new garage door.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have that same attachment and experienced the same failure. It's important, as Greg Hill suggests, that the door be properly balanced on the springs, to ensure that the forces on the mechanism are minimized.

My solution was to create a load spreader bar on the outside of the door, hand-filing square holes to accept suitably sized carriage bolts.

As this was many years ago, some rust has set in. I believe the steel is approximately 1/16" thick and was hand cut from scrap I had in my garage. If it wasn't for the rust, I would have thought it was scrap aluminum.

[image: outer garage door attachment]

Using the appropriate spreader, holes were drilled in the bracket to match:

[image: inner lower nuts]

[image: inner upper nuts]

I'm not sure why the upper bolts were so long. It could have been that I had a limited selection. The vertical bolts of which the heads can be seen in this image were an earlier attempt which eventually failed and are probably lag bolts.

Comment: +1 for nice DIY solution.

Answer (score 1):

You might:

- replace the existing screws with larger screws
- drill fresh holes and move the screws to these
- make friends with a hobby welder and ask them to weld these parts together. It's thin metal, so they'll need to have some degree of skill to avoid burning holes through it, and the paint will burn off the outside wherever the welds are performed. I would (and have) done this with my MIG welder with shield gas; it would be challenging to do this job with a cheap flux-core MIG setup.

The failure of this bracket is a sign that the door has lived a decent amount of life already. It might also be a sign that the door is enduring some excessive stress. Perhaps the springs have worn and the automatic operator is having to pull harder to get the door moving, for example.